How to fix this shadow using a toon shader in Cycles
I am currently working on a very simple toon shader effect for some background assets for a game, I am specifically trying to get as much done in Blender as possible rather than using shaders. I wanted to know if anyone had a fix for this weird shadow that is being cast onto the model. The geometry in question is a cylinder.I get a similarly weird effect with a cube. 
I have no additional lights or HDRIs active, the world is a simple flat colour (currently set to a .7 value no hue or saturation).
here is the material setup:


It's hard to tell only from the cropped screenshots. Why the backface culling? Are you sure the normals are all correct? How many samples do you use? Toon shaders don't need many but transparency does.

You mean game engine shaders, yes?
